# Setup a domain name and nameservers on Leaseweb

Tags: domain, nameserver

How can give a little help?

How I can setup a domain name and nameservers on a VPS hosted at leaseweb.
I have ssh access.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [any of their documentation](http://www.leaseweb.com/en/help) yet?

Comment: +1 for Documentation, but it seems there is no (publicly) available information of leaseweb regarding nameservers.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have read their documentation, but i dont find about question I have made. If you know where I can find it, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

DNS Servers were engineered with stability in mind. And they should also be deployed with regard to the same principle.

So you should be asking yourself:

- Do you need you own DNS?
- Do you have to host it on a VPS?
- Do you plan any redundancy? (*Remember my introduction*)

Then you should start elaborating which server would fit best to you.

- Which features do you need?
- Which sizing do you apply on the servers?

If you've found answers to these questions you should have got further questions. So be welcome to come back and ask qualified questions.

Comment: Hi Pacey Thanks for your awser. I Already have the vps, I pretend host a little website. So because of this I ask about how i can setup server and nameservers.